# How to use pandas read csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where all the column names are dates. When I use `.read_csv()`, pandas reads these column names as strings. Is there a way to specify that I want the column names to be datetime objects.

Ideally I need this to be done as part of the `.read_csv()` call, rather than an additional line afterwards.

For example, the csv file looks something like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'2022-10-25': [0, 1, 1], '2022-10-26': [1, 1, 0]})
```

and when I call `.read_csv()`, I want the column headers to be datetime objects, rather than strings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create the dummy dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'2022-10-25': [0, 1, 1], '2022-10-26': [1, 1, 0]})
```

Check the initial columns index:

```
df.columns
```

**Output:**

[image]

You can run the following code just after the `.read_csv()`

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_columns = [datetime.strptime(col, '%Y-%m-%d') for col in df.columns]
df.columns = pd.Index(datetime_columns, dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Finally we check the new index:

```
df.columns
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: You mentioned it as 'ideally' to do it in `read_csv()`, you didn't mentioned that you know how to do it at all. You cannot do it in `read_csv()'..

Comment: @user112495 is the only way to do it.. Is my answer covers your question?

Comment: @user112495 please be more specific the next time, because I spend time on your question and finally the question changed.. If you didn't have the 'ideally' I would answer completely different.

Answer (score 0):

either you define the whole column as a datetime or as an integer... there is no way you can define the header as a datetime and the values as a different thing.

On the other hand you cannot define your columns as datetime, because the values are just integers... I think you are approaching your problem in a wrong way.

Comment: yes you can define your columns as integers of course, in fact they are integers. But why do you want to define a column with integers as datetime? I just do not get that

Comment: But then just make things simple by replacing the ones by the dates and assign dtype datetime to the columns, maybe defining the format with strftime(). Otherwise the approach will not make sense.